# Nested If statement inside another if in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to write a function such that if the price is not zero it should check that the variable price_label_before is zero, then if should return a certain format or else return something else.

E.g 1

`price_label_before` =USD
Currency= KES
Price=2000

Return USD 2000

E.g 2
`price_label_before`= null
Currency= KES
Price=2000

Return KES 2000

Below is the code:

```
$currency       =   esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_currency_symbol', '') );

$where_currency =   esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_where_currency_symbol', '') );

$price_label_before    =   floatval ( get_post_meta($post_id, 'property_label_before', true) );  

$price  = floatval   ( get_post_meta($post_id, 'property_price', true) );

if ($price != 0 ) {

    if ($price_label_before = 0) {


    $price =wpestate_show_price($post_id,$currency,$where_currency,1);   
     }
     else {
           $myprice = floatval   ( get_post_meta($post_id, 'property_price', true) );

           $price='<span class="price_label price_label_before1">'.$price_label_before. '&nbsp;' .number_format($myprice).'</span><span class="price_label ">'.$price_label.'</span>';  
     }             

}else{

    $price='';

}
```

Comment: And what is the code doing or not doing?

Comment: @JayBlanchard the code is returning 0 2000

Answer (score 1):

Your nested `else` condition will never be met because you're using the assignment operator in your if statement.

```
if ($price_label_before = 0) {
```

Should instead be: <s>`if ($price_label_before == 0) {`</s>

Edit: Update to reflect `empty` condition instead of `0` condition

```
if ($price_label_before == '' ) {
```

Or:

```
if ( empty( $price_label_before ) ) {
```

Right now, it's **setting** `$price_label_before` to 0, and then checking if it's 0 (which is always the case)

This is a difference between an [Assignment Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) and [Comparison Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (Specifically the equality operator)

As a (partly irrelevant to the question) sidenote, I'd try and work on your code consistency with spacing and whitespace to make your code more legible. It seems like you've got lots of random spaces and breaks in your code that will make it hard to read and maintain as your codebase grows larger.

```
$currency       =   esc_html( get_option( 'wp_estate_currency_symbol', '' ) );
$where_currency =   esc_html( get_option( 'wp_estate_where_currency_symbol', '' ) );

$price_label_before = floatval( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'property_label_before', true ) );  
$price              = floatval( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'property_price', true ) );

if( $price != 0 ){
    if( $price_label_before == '' ){
        $price = wpestate_show_price( $post_id, $currency, $where_currency, 1 );   
    } else {
        $myprice = floatval( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'property_price', true ) );
        $price   = '<span class="price_label price_label_before1">'. $price_label_before .'&nbsp;'. number_format( $myprice ) .'</span><span class="price_label ">'. $price_label .'</span>';  
    }
} else {
    $price = '';
}
```

Comment: this still doesn't seem to work the result that is outputted is still returning USD KES 2000, when it is only meant to be USD 2000 or KES 2000 depending on whether $price_label_before is empty or not

Comment: Currently you're comparing it to the value `0` which isn't `empty`. I've updated the large code block to compare it to an empty value instead

Comment: To compare to an empty value, you can use `$price_label_before == ''` or `empty( $price_label_before );`